# CompletableFuture result calculation

Tags: completable-future

What is the difference between
`CompletableFuture.allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])` and
`CompletableFuture.allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futuresList.size()]`

I need to return CompletableFuture<List> at the same time requirement is i want to make sure first task is finished before I call the second and then return the result in CompletableFuture<List> format. If i create list of result first how I will able to return it using CompletableFuture<List>. Any pointer will help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To question 1, according to ArrayList source code,
`futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])` and `futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futuresList.size()])` all lead to the same result.

Difference:

1, size=0, ArrayList create the exact required size to hold new elements.

2, size=futuresList.size(), ArrayList use the supplied array to hold elements, and test if the supplied array has any space left, set a[size] to null.

Best practices: Use size=0

To question 2, some tricks like follow,

```java
    static void play() {
        List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> all = firstTask();
        secondTask();
    }
    
    static List<CompletableFuture<Integer>> firstTask() {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);
        CompletableFuture<Integer> f1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {countDownLatch.countDown(); return 1;});
        CompletableFuture<Integer> f2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {countDownLatch.countDown(); return 2;});
        CompletableFuture<Integer> f3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {countDownLatch.countDown(); return 3;});
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //
        }
        return Arrays.asList(f1, f2, f3);
        
    }
    
    static void secondTask() {
        System.out.println("do secondTask");
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)